# Pasar información de una lista a una celda en Excel

Tags: excel, formulas, excel-2010

Quisiera saber si es posible seleccionar varias opciones de una lista y luego de ser seleccionados, pasarlos a una celda cualquier en Excel, ejemplo: Tengo un lista con 5 países y cuando los voy seleccionando, se colocan en la celda D31. ¿Es posible hacer esto? Hasta el momento he buscado y lo que encuentro es solo al revés de celdas a listas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final pude encontrar la respuesta, espero le sirva a alguien más:

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    For i = 0 To ListBox21.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox21.Selected(i) = True Then
            Numero = Numero + 1
            TextBox1.Text = Numero
            txt_sociedades.Text = txt_sociedades.Text & " " & ListBox21.List(i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub